# add class to a component in jsf template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf-2.2

I'm using a template for my website but I want to add a class to `<li>` element when clicking it , I can do it already as i saw the result in the debug mood but when i moved to this page the `class="active"` which i added is removed again. 
Here is my img in debug mood and the script which i use.
So how can I save the added class to this element?

```js
     <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    $("#liEmpCreate").click(function () {
                        console.log("rerererererer ay2 ay2 ay2 ");
                        $("#liEmpCreate").addClass("active");
                    });
                });
            </script>
```

[result in debug mood before redirect to this page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1iLc.png)

Comment: Are you talking about the sidebar?

Comment: yes the class of the selected <li> element of sidebar.

Comment: is it reloading the page when you click save?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the answer :) .

As I mentioned above in the question , i wanted to add this class to an element of sidebar which refers to the pages i opened. So i have all these elements in all pages, then i put an id foreach

tag and tried to use the same script in each page separately , but unfortunately it doesn't work either.
So i tried to put my script everywhere in my page but when i put it after my form and before   `</ui:define>` i found the console.log appears in the browser console, but it doesn't work as i wished because of this code is called and then the page is rendered again. finally i used the below code and it worked correctly.

```html
    <script>
               $(window).on('load', function() {
                        $("#liEmpCreate").addClass("active");
                });
            </script>
            <h:outputStylesheet library="js2" name="jquery-3.2.1.min.js"/>
        </ui:define>
```